# AutoMapper - Mapping empty string to an int

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper to convert `SourceThing` to `DestinationThing`

```
public class SourceThing
{
    public string Length;
    public string Width;
    public string Make;
}

public class DestinationThing
{
    public int Length;
    public int Width;
    public string Make;
}
```

`CreateMap<SourceThing, DestinationThing>();`

`_mapper.Map<DestinationThing>(sourceObj);`

The issue I have is when my `sourceObj` is the following:

```
{
  "Length": "",
  "Width": "2",
  "Make": "3"
}
```

I get an error: `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` `AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.` `Property: Length`

Is there something I need to configure to allow AutoMapper to map this successfully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [Custom Value Resolvers](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```
CreateMap<SourceThing, DestinationThing>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Length, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Length)
            ? default(int)
            : int.Parse(src.Length))
```